# What are the ethics of sound recording?

Tags: recording, ethics

What are the ethics around the recording of "wildlife" sounds?

What about in situations where anthropogenic noise may also be recorded?

What overlap (if any) do these concerns have with other "ubiquitous monitoring" (cell phones, smart TVs, digital assistants, etc.)

Any good readings that survey ethical concerns of these topics?

Comment: @Flip-- If one of the answers below answers your question, please 'accept' the answer by checking the checkmark under the vote tally. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 11):

I'd highly recommend this paper:

Sandbrook C, Clark D, Toivonen T, Simlai T, O’Donnell S, Cobbe J, Adams W. 2021. Principles for the socially responsible use of conservation monitoring technology and data. Conserv Sci Pract [Internet]. [accessed 2021 Aug 11] 3(5):e374. https://doi.org/10.1111/CSP2.374

I'd also recommend [This panel discussion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZPp7BIDVj8) hosted by WildLabs.

There are a couple issues at play, one of which is the ethical questions in absolute terms, and the other of which is how one goes through the regulatory and compliance bodies that are often involved in academic research.

Comment: Do the references address the ethics of sound recording in particular or are they more general?

Comment: @Noil they're both pretty general rather than specific to acoustics.

Answer (score 8):

There was a discussion about the use of playbacks specifically here as well: [Is it cruel/unethical to playback bird sounds to birds in my yard?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/348/is-it-cruel-unethical-to-playback-bird-sounds-to-birds-in-my-yard/362#362)

Comment: Good point Carly! We start having many questions and we should start making links between each of them indeed. I actually missed this question, so thanks! As SE usually works, I believe that this should go as a comment under the question. In SE, I often see comments e.g. : "related: LINK_to_related_question"

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for pointing that out!